# Slow and Disabled Add-ins for Outlook

Tags: outlook-addin

I have created an add-in for outlook but I cannot get it installed on one person's computer.

Here is the message she gets:

[image: Add-In Error Popup]

I am posting this on stack as opposed to another site because we are the developers  so it might be a development issue.

Here is what I have tried to get rid of this message:

1. exiting outlook.
2. uninstalling plugin from control panel.
3. rebooting computer.
4. starting outlook and observing that the add-in is gone.
5. install the add-in using the setup.exe that is generated by visual-studio
6. observe that add-in is not active and that the error message above is displayed.

This add-on works on several other people's machines.

What is different for this person is that she was the first to have it installed so she had a version that did have a startup issue that I would expect this error.

I suspect that somehow outlook is "remembering" the add-in rather than the add-in is still failing.

Two questions:

1. What can I do to get it installed?
2. What can I do to detect this in the add-in so I can report it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your addin's key to 1 in

```
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\AddinList
```

and

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DoNotDisableAddinList
```

and delete it from

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems
```

"16" in the keys above refers to the Outlook version (16 for 2016, 15 for 2013, etc.)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I had to be persistent to find the items in the registry.